# Como aplicar mock no "new Date()" utilizando o Jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jest

Por favor, alguém sabe como aplicar *mock* no `new Date()` utilizando o Jest?

Tentei fazer assim, mas não funcionou. A data continua atual:

```js
jest.spyOn(Date, 'now').mockImplementation(() => {
    return new Date(2020, 9, 1, 7).getTime();
})

console.log(new Date());
console.log(new Date(Date.now()));
```

Resultado:

```bsh
console.log
  2020-10-30T16:16:44.122Z

console.log
  2020-10-01T10:00:00.000Z
```

Existe alguma coisa que desconheço. Hum ...

Comment: @LuizFelipe o`Date.now()` está funcionando sim, mas o que estou precisando é de "mockar" o `new Date()`. É sem utilizar o `Date.now()`. Entendeu? 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A resposta do [Luiz Felipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/69296/luiz-felipe) foi muito esclarecedora, por este motivo aceitei a resposta dele. ✅
Mas estou postando aqui também a minha resposta.

A partir do Jest 26, isto pode ser alcançado utilizando temporizadores falsos "modernos".

Esta foi a melhor solução que encontrei nos sites gringos:

```js
jest.useFakeTimers('modern').setSystemTime(new Date(2020, 9, 1, 7));

console.log(new Date());
console.log(new Date(Date.now()));
```

Resultado:

```bsh
console.log
  2020-10-01T10:00:00.000Z

console.log
  2020-10-01T10:00:00.000Z
```

Referências:
https://jestjs.io/blog/2020/05/05/jest-26#new-fake-timers
(Acessado em 30 de outubro de 2020)

https://github.com/sinonjs/fake-timers/blob/master/README.md#clocksetsystemtimenow
(Acessado em 30 de outubro de 2020)

Comment: Excelente. Não sabia deles; inclusive sugiro que aceite esta resposta ao invés da minha (que é, sem dúvidas, mais útil para _mock_ de datas). :-)

Comment: Tudo bem então. Já que vc pediu. 
Mas recado do Stack Overflow: _"Você pode aceitar sua própria resposta em 2 dias."_

Comment: Achei muito bom essa tb... ficou bem mais simples e pelo que li, é para isso essa função. (ref.: https://testing-library.com/docs/using-fake-timers/)

Answer (score 5):

O `Date` é um objeto global no JavaScript. Isso significa que é uma propriedade de `window` (no *browser*), de `global` (no Node.js) ou de `globalThis` (em *browsers* modernos e em versões recentes do Node.js).

Como o Jest roda no Node.js, podemos utilizar o `global` para acessá-la. A partir do Node.js  12.4.0 pode-se utilizar `globalThis` também.

Desse modo, para *mockar* `Date`, devemos "espiar" o objeto que o contém. Assim:

```js
const mockedDate = new Date(2000, 9, 1, 7);
jest.spyOn(global, 'Date').mockImplementation(() => {
  return mockedDate;
});
```

Como está utilizando TypeScript, no caso específico do *mock* de `Date`, há de se passar `any` como "argumento" para os dois genéricos de `spyOn`, já que as definições de tipo do Jest possuem um certo conflito em relação ao tipo de `Date`. Isso porque `Date` pode ser aplicada (retornando tipo `string`) ou instanciada, retornando tipo `Date`. Como os dois casos são possíveis, o TypeScript não é capaz de definir [qual dos *overloads*](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/1f0215a03aebef023a5f48da0895eb23eb9a01d8/types/jest/index.d.ts#L300) será usado.

Portanto, como a definição de tipos só levaria o primeiro caso em conta (no caso, `string`), temos que fazer:

```
const mockedDate = new Date(2000, 9, 1, 7);
//        ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
jest.spyOn<any, any>(global, 'Date').mockImplementation(() => {
  return mockedDate;
})
```

Agora sempre que você construir uma nova data, terá ela mockada. Note que tivemos que instanciar a data a ser retornada pelo *mock* fora do *callback* de `mockImplementation` para não cair em um *loop* infinito.

Se dermos um `console.log(new Date())` agora teremos a seguinte saída:

```
console.log
  2000-10-01T10:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta.  Experimentei seu código, mas aqui no meu PC ele causa este problema ao rodar os testes:

```bash
error TS2345: Argument of type '() => Date' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => string'.
      Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'string'.

    28          jest.spyOn(global, 'Date').mockImplementation(() => {
                                                              ~~~~~~~
```
Hum ...  será por quê?

Comment: @DeividsonDamasio, editei a resposta. :-)

Comment: Desculpe-me, acabei colocando a tag *javascript* no enunciado da pergunta e isto causou uma certa confusão. ‍♂️
Vou aceitar a sua resposta ✅ porque ela foi muito esclarecedora, mas vou postar a minha resposta aqui também. 