# Como verificar o tipo de um valor em teste unitário utilizando Jest?

Tags: javascript, tipagem, testes-de-unidade, jest

Possuo uma função que retorna um objeto com duas propriedades: nome e id, onde nome receberá seu valor por parâmetro e o id é gerado automaticamente pelo `Date.now()`.

Meu objetivo é criar um teste no Jest que verifica se o valor de id é do tipo numérico, já que não posso comparar seu valor exato

A função de criação do objeto:

```
const createNewTodo = (addTodoInputValue) => {
  const newTodo = {
    id: Date.now(),
    name: addTodoInputValue
  }

  return newTodo
}
```

Comment: Talvez possa ser útil: [Como aplicar mock no “new Date()” utilizando o Jest?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/480115/69296)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quer testar o tipo de algum valor em JavaScript, nada impede de fazer uma assertiva utilizando o operador **[`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)**.

Assim, por exemplo, para verificar se algum valor `<value>` tem tipo numérico, faz-se:

```
assert(typeof <value> === 'number');
```

Utilizando a API do Jest:

```
expect(typeof <value>).toBe('number');
```

---

No seu exemplo:

```
const todo = createNewTodo('Learn Jest');
expect(typeof todo.id).toBe('number'); // <-- Asserção aqui.
```